# Odds of one person getting more odd numbers on a die than another

Tags: probability

**First player rolls a 6-sided die 100 times and the second player 101 times. What are the odds of the second player getting more odd numbers than the first one?**

I tried solving this via listing the options which led to a nasty sum that I wasn't able to solve neither by hand nor by using wolfram alpha. Clearly there has to be a more clever solution using the properties of a binomial distribution, but so far I haven't come across anything useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's $\frac 12$.

Let $\psi$ be the probability that they are tied after $100$ throws (from each).

There are two ways player $2$ can win:

A.  Player $2$ can be ahead after $100$ throws from each, probability $\frac 12\times (1-\psi)$.

B.  They can be tied at $100$ and player $2$ might throw an odd number on the $101^{st}$, probability $\frac 12\times \psi$.

Thus the total probability that player $2$ wins is $$\frac 12\times (1-\psi)+\frac 12\times \psi=\boxed {\frac 12}$$

Comment: cool. What's the rationale for multiplying 1/2 with $1-\psi$ and $\psi$ in parts A and B respectively?

Comment: I mean I get that 0.5 is the probability of getting a head but I don't get why it gets multiplied by $\psi$.

Comment: In part $A$:  if the game is not tied (prob. $1-\psi$) then we know that one of the players won and, by symmetry, they have equal chances of winning.  Thus, the probability that player $2$ won, given that there was not a tie is $\frac 12$.  in part $B$: you need a tie for the first $100$ games ($\psi$) and you need player $2$ to throw $H$ ($\frac 12$).

Comment: great, thanks for the clarification.